# Deal with ticker name with Number in quantmod

Tags: r, finance, quantmod

```
require(quantmod)
wateroasis <- getSymbols("1161.hk", auto.assign=FALSE)
# Then I get the stock prices

>1161.HK
Error: unexpected symbol in "1161.HK"
```

However, if I tried another ticker such as "AAPL" the problem doesn't exist.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You set `auto.assign=FALSE` and assigned the output of `getSymbols` to `wateroasis`. Why do you expect the `1161.HK` object to even exist?  If you left `auto.assign=TRUE` (the default), you can access `1161.HK` by wrapping it in back-ticks `\`1161.HK\``

Comment: Thanks Joshua, that's the point!