# quantmod barChart cant be displayed

Tags: r, quantmod

I am using quantmod to get certain shares data displayed.

```
getSymbols("COP")
barChart(COP)
```

No problem to displayed the above barChart, but how to go about displaying barchart like this one example below.

```
 getSymbols("0636.HK")
 barChart(0636.HK)
```

Error : chartSeries requires an xtsible object

I suspect something to do with numbers or the dot. Any help is appreciated?

Comment: `out <- getSymbols("0636.HK", env = NULL); barChart(out)` works.

Comment: Fantastic @Pascal, this is my second encounter with backtick as the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(quantmod)

getSymbols("0636.HK")
# backticks required according to 
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807006/deal-with-ticker-name-with-number-in-quantmod
barChart(`0636.HK`)
```

or

```
out <- getSymbols("0636.HK", env = NULL)
barChart(out, name = "0636.HK")
```

[image]